# Pandas: Calculate of max value from filtered elements from the same group

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an input data frame like this:

```
# input data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("A", 11, 1),
        ("A", 12, 2),
        ("A", 13, 3),
        ("A", 14, 4),
        ("B", 21, 1),
        ("B", 22, 2),
        ("B", 23, 3),
        ("B", 24, 4)       
    ],
    columns=("key", "ord", "val"),
)
```

[image]

I am looking for a simple way (without iteration) to calculate for each group (key) and each group element the maximal of previous values from the previous rows in the same group the result should be like this:

```
# wanted output data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("A", 11, 1, np.NaN), # no previous element in this group, so it should be Nul
        ("A", 12, 2, 1),      # max of vals = [1]     in group "A" and ord < 12
        ("A", 13, 3, 2),      # max of vals = [1,2]   in group "A" and ord < 13
        ("A", 14, 4, 3),      # max of vals = [1,2,3] in group "A" and ord < 14
        
        ("B", 21, 2, np.NaN),
        ("B", 22, 3, 2),
        ("B", 23, 4, 3),
        ("B", 24, 5, 4),       
    ],
    columns=("key", "ord", "val", "max_val_before"),
)
```

[image]

I tried to group and filter but my solution do not give me the expected results. I this possible without iterating each row manually? Thank you very much.

I have saved the notebook also on Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/maciejbednarz/mean-previous

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `cummax` with `shift`

```
df.groupby('key').val.apply(lambda x : x.cummax().shift())
Out[221]: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
5    1.0
6    2.0
7    3.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Beny: Thank you very much, very good solution. Is it also possible not take all elements not only by index as your sultion but also to filter previous elements by value. something like: "take previous elements where 'ord' < current 'ord' ?